# doopl parameter setting in python

Tags: python-3.x, cplex, docplex, docplexcloud

I'm playing with doopl in python.

And I would like to set minimal gap tolerance with

`opl.cplex_stats.MiPRelativeGap()=5`

which doesn't work.

If possible, I want to make run-time limit.

But I couldn't find and resources that has does parameter settings.

I believe it is not allowed. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do that in the opl model itself

See

https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zoosetting1.mod

And use cplex.epgap = 0.05;

Comment: This is awesome! I really appreciate it